# ObjectUnsubscribedError after using takeUntil

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have a bunch of http requests happening while I load different items to the screen.  this is the basic layout

```
ngUnsubscribe: any = new Subject();

constructor(private service: Service){}

ngOnInit() {}

BuildView(data) {this.submitLayerservice.submitLayer(onLoadSubmitLayerFormat)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe( //logic happens here 
)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
}
```

Everything works fine and I see all of the requests get canceled when the component is destroyed.  But when I go to load the project again I get this error and nothing shows up.  I'm guessing it's because the ngUnsubscribe already happened?  Not really sure.  Most of the questions for this have to deal with Map.

EDIT:
If i dont add this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();  The problem seems to be fixed.  Should I not unsubscribe from this subject?

Comment: When do you call `BuildView`?

Comment: I call build view when a user clicks to load a project.

Comment: Can you please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can reproduce your error

Comment: maybe call this.ngUnsubscribe.next(); then this.ngUnsubscribe.complete(); before unsubscribe, according to the article

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking for this ,most likely the issue because the Subscription is not created again when you enter the component , so add in the 
ngWillEnter or ngDidEnter

ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();

make sure you have created the Subscription when you enter the view.